# PDFKit iOS 15 printing pdf page incorrectly

Tags: pdfkit, ios15

when calling PDFPage.draw the first page of the pdf prints by repeating the first word over and over. Only in iOS15 do all other iOS versions print the page normally. Resaving the document in acrobat with 'optimized' on fixes the issue. However, we can't guarantee our users will do that before uploading a pdf to our system.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?